# System of equations from weighted Gaussian Quadrature

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I've been working on a weighted Gaussian Quadrature problem for a Numerical Analysis class and have been having the hardest time.  The problem boils down to solving a system of four equations:
$$
  \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
  1 = a_0 + a_1 \\ 
  \frac{1}{4} = a_0 x_0 + a_1 x_1 \\ 
  \frac{1}{9} = a_0 x_0^2 + a_1 x_1^2 \\ 
  \frac{1}{16} = a_0 x_0^3 + a_1 x_1 ^3 \\ 
  \end{array}
  \right.
$$
I know that we can write this in matrix form as 
$$
  \left( \begin{matrix}
  1 & 1 \\
  x_0 & x_1 \\
  x_0^2 & x_1^2 \\
  x_0^3 & x_1^3  \\
  \end{matrix} \right)
  \left( \begin{matrix}
  a_0 \\
  a_1 \\
  \end{matrix} \right)
   = \left( \begin{matrix}
   1 \\
   1/4 \\
   1/9 \\
   1/16 \\
   \end{matrix} \right)
$$
My Professor sold it as solvable because it's a system of four equations in the four unknowns $a_0 , a_1 , x_0, x_1$, but I'm not sure how to proceed given that we have higher powers of $x_0$ and $x_1$.  This seems like it should be a relatively easy linear algebra question, but I'm stumped.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The problem is--assuming we are indeed trying to solve for $a_0, a_1, x_0, x_1$--that you are trying to shoehorn a non-linear system into a linear form. Typically, we *choose* our $x_0, x_1$, or we compute them by some other means. This would give us an overdetermined linear system. In this case, if we wish to solve for the nodes and their coefficients, then we have to use a non-linear solution method, e.g. Newton's method.

Comment: The weights and nodes can be determined exactly in this case.   Solve the first two equations for $a_0,a_1$ and substitute in the second two equations.   You should (after simplification) get a pair of quadratic equations in $x_0,x_1.$

Comment: Yes.  You need the solution of all four simultaneously.    Solving the first two eliminates $a_0,a_1:$   E.g.  $a_0 = \frac{4x_1 - 1}{4(x_1-x_0)},$  $a_1=\frac{4x_0-1}{4(x_0-x_1)}.$

Comment: Following your procedure, Matt, I come to two equations:
$$ 
x_0 ^2 - 4 x_1 x_0 ^2 - x_1 ^2 + 4 x_0 x_1^2 = 4/9 (x_0 - x_1)
$$
and
$$
x_0^3 - 4 x_1 x_0^3 - x_1^3 + 4x_0 x_1^3 = 1/4 (x_0 - x_1)
$$
I'm still not too sure how to solve these simultaneously..

Comment: I am assuming your algebra is correct and proceeding from there.  On your first and second equations, factor $(x_0-x_1)$ (grouping) on the left hand side,  you should get:  
For Equation 1:   $(x_0-x_1)(x_0+x_1) - 4x_0x_1 (x_0-x_1) = \frac{4}{9}(x_0 - x_1).$  And for  Equation 2:  $(x_0-x_1)(x_1^2+x_0x_1 + x_0^2)  - 4x_0 x_1 (x_0+x_1)(x_0 - x_1) = \frac{1}{4} (x_0 - x_1).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the equations$$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
  1 = a_0 + a_1 \\ 
  \frac{1}{4} = a_0 x_0 + a_1 x_1 \\ 
  \frac{1}{9} = a_0 x_0^2 + a_1 x_1^2 \\ 
  \frac{1}{16} = a_0 x_0^3 + a_1 x_1 ^3 \\ 
  \end{array}
  \right.$$
use the first and second to eliminate $a_0$ and $a_1$ as functions of $x_0$ and $x_1$; this leads to $$a_0=-\frac{4 {x_1}-1}{4 ({x_0}-{x_1})}$$ $$a_1=1-\frac{4 {x_1}-1}{4 ({x_0}-{x_1})}$$ Plug these into the third equation which becomes $$\frac{1}{36} ({x_0} (9-36 {x_1})+9 {x_1}-4)=0$$ from which $x_0$ can be eliminated $$x_0=\frac{9 {x_1}-4}{9 (4 {x_1}-1)}$$ Now, the fourth equation becomes $$\frac{36 {x_1} (7 {x_1}-5)+17}{1296 (4 {x_1}-1)}=0$$ that is to say $$252 {x_1}^2-180 {x_1}+17=0$$ for which the roots are $$\frac{1}{42} \left(15 \pm\sqrt{106}\right)$$
I am sure that you can take from here and finally get

$$\left\{a_0=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{9}{4 \sqrt{106}},a_1=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{9}{4
   \sqrt{106}},x_0=\frac{1}{42} \left(15+\sqrt{106}\right),x_1=\frac{1}{42}
   \left(15-\sqrt{106}\right)\right\}$$ $$\left\{a_0=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{9}{4 \sqrt{106}},a_1=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{9}{4
   \sqrt{106}},x_0=\frac{1}{42} \left(15-\sqrt{106}\right),x_1=\frac{1}{42}
   \left(15+\sqrt{106}\right)\right\}$$